# How to change envelope sender address using phpmailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

With php mail() I can write

```
mail('to@example.com','subject!','body','From: from@example.com','-f from@example.com');
```

But how can I do the same with phpmailer ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This example shows how.](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/AdvancedMail)

the relevant lines:

```
$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
$mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
```

As [Hannes Morgenstern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18053334/4692205) correctly suggested, the answer is:

```
$pMail->Sender='admin@yourdomain.com';
$pMail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last', FALSE);
```

Comment: I don't believe that `SetFrom()` or `AddReplyTo()` address the OP's questions of *envelope* sender. See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/a/18053334/4692205 regarding `Sender` variable.

Answer (score 21):

The relevant line in Theolodis answer is:

```
$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
```

There is no need to use `AddReplyTo()` this is something completely different.

You only need to set your from address (and name optionally) by using `SetFrom()`. If you look at the [code](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php#L1076), `SetFrom()` takes three parameters:

```
/**
 * Set the From and FromName properties
 * @param string $address
 * @param string $name
 * @param boolean $auto Whether to also set the Sender address, defaults to true
 * @throws phpmailerException
 * @return boolean
 */
public function SetFrom($address, $name = '', $auto = true) {
....
```

the third parameter (defaults to true) and therefor the envelope sender gets set to the same address as the sender.

It gets interesting if you want to set different addresses as envelope sender and From Address. This is the way how to **CHANGE** envelope sender. Therefor you have to set the [`$sender`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L100) property of your `PHPMailer` instance like this:

```
  $pMail->Sender='admin@yourdomain.com';
  $pMail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last', FALSE);
```

Answer (score 2):

The -f flag is set with $email->Sender

This is the Envelope From which allows the email server to evaluate the sender's email address before receiving the rest of your email data

SetFrom - this is what email address the end user will see as the message coming from

AddReplyTo - this is what email address will pop up if they reply to the email

Sender needs to be clean to pass spam filters

SetFrom needs to be clean to pass spam filters

AddReplyTo doesn't really matter.  This allows a service to send an email on behalf of a user with an email address not managed by the service.

Comment: This is the ONLY correct answer. The other answers set the "From" header... NOT... the actual sender in the mail envelope - as per the question. That being said, I think the OP actually wanted to change the "From" header.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me (obscurely) using

```
$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'Rupert Bear');
```

was to use localhost rather than directly access the smtp server e.g.

```
$email->Host='localhost'; // SMTP server this way you get from name (don't know why)
```

Now mails arrive in Outlook from 'Rupert Bear' [name@yourdomain.com]

Answer (score 0):

> As Hannes Morgenstern correctly suggested, the answer is:

```
$pMail->Sender='admin@yourdomain.com';
$pMail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last', FALSE);
```

The order is important. First

```
$pMail->Sender='admin@yourdomain.com';
```

second

```
$pMail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last', FALSE);
```

Otherwise it won't work as Sender gets overwritten.