# Message was not sent.Mailer error: SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm new in Php and find a Php mailer class to send email but getting following error.

Error Message:

```
Message was not sent.Mailer error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

Php Code:

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "smtp.impeccableplus.com"; // SMTP server

$mail->From     = "from@example.com";
$mail->AddAddress("email@gmail.com");

$mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
$mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message was not sent.';
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent.';
}

?>
```

Thanks.

**Update:**

I just change the host name = localhost. Now it's successfully sent email but problem is, It's showing the mail in spam folder. Why ?

Comment: Something went wrong. PHPMailer has a `SMTPDebug` option. [Debugging PHP Mail() and/or PHPMailer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2896280)

Comment: check your mail server credential too

Comment: @Pekka웃 I just change the host name = localhost. Now it's successfully sent email but problem is, It's showing the mail in spam folder. Why ? and showing sender name = root user, why ?

Comment: [From issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918999/how-to-change-envelope-sender-address-using-phpmailer)

Comment: [spam issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717257/phpmailer-mails-going-straight-to-spam)

Comment: When you change to sending through localhost, you are no longer using your upstream mail server, you probably have zero sending reputation, so you're likely to get marked as spam. Also if you're sending via localhost, you don't need to use SMTP - call `IsMail()` instead of `IsSMTP()`.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a number of reasons for this:

- Your SMTP server `smtp.impeccableplus.com` could be blacklisted. You can [check if your SMTP server is being blacklisted](https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx)
- The `from address` could be regarded as spammy, especially if you're using `from@example.com`
- Some mail clients (such as Gmail) do not like the fact that you are sending an email "from" someone else's address if it really didn't originate from that address
- and possibly 20+ other reasons

You should consider setting up **SPF** and **DKIM** for your email address that you are sending emails from. Read [this](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404314/how-can-i-create-an-spf-record-for-my-domain) and [this](http://www.gettingemaildelivered.com/dkim-explained-how-to-set-up-and-use-domainkeys-identified-mail-effectively). By Setting up SPF and DKIM, you are essentially authenticating the email which considerably improves mail delivery.

Alternatively, if you really get stuck, consider using a mail delivery API such as [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/).