# PHP mail from address

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using phpmailer to send email from my online website.but when i sending it showing default server address in from address

```
<?php
require_once 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); //defaults to using php "mail()"; the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

try {
  $mail->AddAddress('to@domain.com', 'Jo');
  $mail->SetFrom('info@mydomain.com', 'Info');
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
  $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
  $mail->MsgHTML('Helooo');

  $mail->Send();
  echo "Message Sent OK<p></p>\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
?>
```

now it showing like

[image]

i want to replace red marked address to `info@mydomain.com`....how can i do that...this red marked address is default server address i think. i tried to set address using phpmailer from tag, but no change

Comment: Try the solution on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13919132/4608052

Answer (score 0):

try this to change from address

```
<?php
  $to = "somebody@example.com";
  $subject = "My subject";
  $txt = "Hello world!";
  $headers = "From: info@domain.com";

  mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: also try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918999/how-to-change-envelope-sender-address-using-phpmailer

Comment: Don't call `mail()` yourself.

Answer (score -1):

It's very common for hosted email services (e.g. gmail) to not let you change the From address, or restrict you to pre-set aliases, not allowing arbitrary addresses.

It also looks like you've based your code on an obsolete example, and you're probably using an old version of PHPMailer, so [get the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).