# phpMailer not able to see the envelope in the email raw body message

Tags: php, phpmailer

Using the below code snippet, i am getting the envelope from option . But how to do the same in PHPMailer, i tried setting $mail->Sender = 'user2@exdoamin.com' and also replyTO all options but didn't see the envelope in the raw message headers. i am using SMTP server and SMTP authentication method to send emails. Request you to provide any inputs / suggestions on this issue.

```
<?php
mail('user1@yahoo.com','subject!','body!','From: user2@exdomain.com','-f user2@exdomain.com');
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change envelope sender address using phpmailer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918999/how-to-change-envelope-sender-address-using-phpmailer)

Comment: i tired that but didn't worked. I am using SMTP server and authentication to send email .

Comment: You should post the code you're having issues with so we don't need to spend time giving suggestions that you've already tried. But if that didn't work, it seems like there's something else messing with it. Perhaps the SMTP?

Answer (score 1):

The envelope sender is an SMTP-level thing and doesn't necessarily appear in the headers of a sent message - a return-path header containing the envelope sender address is usually added by a *receiving* server. You should not need to set the envelope sender address unless it's different from the from address, for example if you're using VERP addressing for bounce handling. Look at the examples that are provided with PHPMailer. Bear in mind that some ISP's (like gmail) do not allow you to change the from address.