# Get copy to sender with correct email adress / phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

i using a very simple phpmailer script for a contact page.

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['name']) )
{
    $to = 'info@xxx.xxxx'; // Replace with your email

    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'] . "\n\n" . 'Regards, ' . $_POST['name'] . '.';
    $headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if( $_POST['copy'] == 'on' )
    {
        mail($_POST['email'], $subject, $message, $headers2);
    }
}
?>
```

but the issue is, that if copy is send, it has wrong "from" header details...so in example:

```
From: yakashimoto@xzy.xx
Reply to: yakashimoto@xzy.xx
To: yakashimoto@xzy.xx
```

```
but i need
From: info@xxx.xxx
reply to: info@xx.xxx
to: yakashimoto@xyz.xx
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change envelope sender address using phpmailer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918999/how-to-change-envelope-sender-address-using-phpmailer)

Answer (score 0):

This will usually not work because it's forgery, and most hosting providers will not allow it, for example gmail does not.

The right way to do this is to put your own email address in both `from` and `to` headers, and the submitter's address in a `reply-to`.

Though your code is short, it is a spam gateway that attackers could exploit to send unlimited amounts of email through your contact form. I suggest you start again with some better-protected code, such as [the contact form example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps) that you tagged this question with.